# Spring add placeholder value at runtime

Tags: java, spring, properties, configuration, applicationcontext

Suppose having the following Spring configuration where `genericDirectory` placeholder is unknown at compile time:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("${genericDirectory}/additional.properties")
public class SomeConfiguration{
  //...
}
```

I tried to add a property before refreshing context, but still get exception

```
public static BeanFactory createContext(String genericDirectoryName) {
   AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();

   PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();

   Properties props = new Properties();
   props.setProperty("genericDirectory", genericDirectoryName);

   configurer.setProperties(props);

   applicationContext.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(configurer);

   applicationContext.register(SomeConfiguration.class);

   applicationContext.refresh(); // throws IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'genericDirectory' 

   return applicationContext;
}
```

I also tried to set the property in parent context and pass it to child via `setParent` method, but didn't succeed (got the same exception).

Please, show how to add a property to ApplicationContext in runtime.

PS. there's no hidden configuration in this case - context is created manually as is.

Comment: That is never going to work. Placeholders in `@PropertySource` annotations are only resolved against environment variables and system variables not against other properties. So you will need to set it with `System.setProperty` to have it resolved. Or instead of using a `@PropertySource` add a `ResourcePropertySource` manually based on the properties passed in.

Comment: @M.Denium, thanks a lot! `System.setProperty` is also an acceptable way. If you wish the comment could become an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolving properties isn't a multi pass process. When using placeholders in `@PropertySource` those are only resolved against environment variables or system variables (the ones passed with `-D` to your program).

So instead of doing what you have now instead just simply call `System.setProperty`.

```
public static BeanFactory createContext(String genericDirectoryName) {
    System.setProperty("genericDirectory", genericDirectoryName);

   AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
   applicationContext.refresh(); 
   return applicationContext;
}
```

This should let the attribute being resolved.

Also to actually make the `@PropertySource` work you also need to register a `PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer` in your configuration.